# How upload file and FormData in one method without saving file on disk on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, upload

I want to upload file and some `FormData` to server. I'm did it like that and it is works:

On client side i use Angular 2 and logic looks follows:

1.In component

```
onLoadForeignLightCompanies(event: any) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();

        formData.append('projectId', this.projectId);
        formData.append('file', file);
        this.companyService.uploadForeginLightCompany(formData).then(result => {});
        this.isLoading = false;
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

2.In service

```
uploadForeginLightCompany(formData: FormData): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'foreignLightCompanyImport', formData).toPromise();
}
```

On server side

```
public byte[] LoadUploadedFile(HttpPostedFile uploadedFile)
{
    var buf = new byte[uploadedFile.InputStream.Length];
    uploadedFile.InputStream.Read(buf, 0, (int)uploadedFile.InputStream.Length);
    return buf;
}

[HttpPost, Route("foreignLightCompanyImport")]
public async  void UploadForeignLigtCompanyCompanyFile()
{
    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");

    var file = LoadUploadedFile(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]);

    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var projectId = provider.FormData.GetValues("projectId")[0];

    ((IForeginLightCompanyService) Service).UploadDataFromExcel(file, Convert.ToInt32(projectId));
}
```

The following construction is used on the server side. `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");` 
But in this case, the files are stored on disk. I know how to upload a file without saving it to disk. But in this case I can not get other parameters. Like `projectId` e.t.c.

How this be made without saving file on disk?
May be i must using model on client side and send file like binary string in json with other parameters?
Is anybody knows a solution of this issue or maybe have thoughts on it?

Answer (score 2):

A clean way would be to use a model:

```
public class UploadForeignLigtCompanyCompanyFile
{
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }             
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

And change your post action method to have a parameter of the model type:

```
public async void UploadForeignLigtCompanyCompanyFile(
    UploadForeignLigtCompanyCompanyFile companyFile)
{
    // code...
}
```

Of course you will need to change your view code to submit that info to the action method.

Comment: Pleace look at the changes. I added more details.